# Android - navigation bar with overlay in landscape

Tags: android, overlay, android-appcompat, navigationbar

In my application, I am trying to make navigation bar overlaying the content of activity. In portrait mode, it works fine. Navigation bar overlays the content.
When I change the orientation to landscape, then there is navigation bar situated to the right side of the screen. And in this landscape mode, navigation bar does not overlays my content. 
I have implemented a feature for turning on and off a fullscreen mode. When I turn on the fullscreen in landscape mode, my content of activity jumped to left, due to not overlaying navigation bar.
Previously, I was targeting sdk version 18 and it worked fine. Now I am targeting sdk version 22 and I have this problem.

In my `onCreate`, there I have these lines:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);
} else {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Method for enabling fullscreen mode follows:

```
protected void fullscreenOn() {
    if (mActivity != null && !mSearchModeOn) {
        Window window = mActivity.getWindow();
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View
                    .SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View
                    .SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            mActionBar.hide();
        }
        mActionBar.hide();

        bottomBarsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mIsFullscreenOn = true;

    }
}
```

It is weird that in portrait it works fine, but in landscape not. Can anybody help me?

**UPDATE**

**Note:** In my layout, I have set `fitsSystemWindow` attribute to `true`.

**UPDATE 2**

I am using the same layout for portrait and for landscape. Also, I noticed that this weird behavior is only on device with Android 5 (API 21) and higher. I tested it on device with KitKat and it works fine.

Comment: The `fitsSystemWindow` if true exactly does that: it adjusts the padding to leave space for the system windows. Are there two different layouts for portrait and landscape?

Comment: @GPack See my second update, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue. I added following line into my style of activity.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
```